# Java common utilities to get list size and last object

Tags: java, collections, utilities

Even if it's easy to make an handle make, but I wonder if there is any famous helper help to get the size of a list or to get the last object of a list. I think it is really a popular requirements, but I couldn't found one.

```
size = list==null? 0: list.size();
lastObject = isEmpty(list)? null:list.get(list.size() - 1).
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Those don't seem all that helpful to me. I try to initialize my lists so they're not null, so the first one is not useful at all. As for the second, it's no more useful to get back a possibly-null object (which then has to be tested to see if it's null) than it is to check the size of the list first.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a helper method for this AFAIK. One thing you should make sure is that when writing your own helper utility, pay special attention to your target collection. If it is a `List`, avoid using `get(index)` since it is not very efficient for a linked list implementation. If it is an `ArrayList` or in general any collection which implements `RandomAccess`, `get` is very efficient. The most generic way would be to obtain an iterator for the last element and invoke `next()` on it if it exists.

```
public static <T> T getLast(final List<T> list) {
    final ListIterator<T> listIterator = list.listIterator(list.size());
    return listIterator.hasPrevious() ? listIterator.previous() : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Guava has a [getLast method](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#getLast%28java.lang.Iterable%29). However, I couldn't find a size method that handles null Collections.